# Помогите составить регулярное выражение для проверки на содержания строки типа [id123456789|Иван]

Tags: python, регулярные-выражения

Помогите составить регулярное выражение для проверки на содержания строки типа `[id123456789|Иван]`
`[club123456789|Группа]`

Первая половина строки `id123456789` - это какой-то id страницы группы/человека в ВК. Если id группы, то оно представляет из себя строку вида `club123456789`

Вторая половина `Иван` - Набор символов, имя пользователя

Comment: вы можете привести примеры строк которые вы ищете и такие, которые не удовлетворяют условию?

Comment: первая половина это id страницы в ВК, вторая половина - имя

Comment: вы можете сформулировать вопрос следующим образом - у меня есть следующие строки: ... Мне надо из данных строк найти следующие (под)строки: ... ?

Comment: а в чем проблема? `re.search(r'\w+\|\w+', my_string)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Исходя из представленных данных:

`[id123456789|Иван] [club123456789|Группа]`

Можно составить такую нехитрую регулярку:

```
\[(id|club)\d{9}\W[АA-ЯZ][аa-яz]{2,48}\]
```

Пояснения:

`W[АA-ЯZ][аa-яz]` - знаю что имена в ВК бывают и с использованием латиницы

`{2,48}` - минимальная длина имени в ВК 2 символа, а максимальная 48

Остальное думаю понятно..

Ну и чтобы понять, содержит строка подстроку с таким содержанием на питоне:

```
import re
r = bool(re.search(r'\[(id|club)\d{9}\W[АA-ЯZ][аa-яz]{2,48}\]', '[id123456789|Иван] , привет'))
```

Answer (score 0):

Можете потренироваться с регулярными выражениями на [Pythex](https://pythex.org/).
А как писать регулярки можете подсмотреть на [cheatography](https://www.cheatography.com/davechild/cheat-sheets/regular-expressions/).

Если вам нужно было выделить из этого списка:

```
[id123456989|Иван]  
[id123454389|Майкл]  
[id123452289|Коля]
```

то,
`re.search(r'id\d{9}\W[А-Я][а-я]{3,4}').replace("|", " ")`